# Check if item of list is in [x][0] of other list with comprehension

Tags: python, list, compare, exists, dimensional

this one is driving me crazy.
The first list contains filenames without extension. e.g.:

```
afilenames = [file1, file2, file3]
```

The second list contains filenames with extensions:

```
bfiles = [[file1, .exe], [file2, .txt], [file4, ini]]
```

I know would like to get a list, which returns the files from afilenames, which contains in bfiles.

Expected result:

```
[file1, file2]
```

This is my attempt, but it just return bullshit:

```
[afile for afile in afilenames for bfile in bfiles if afile in bfile[0]]
```

Comment: Are you sure? I tested that and it returns the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want

```
files = [file for file, _ in bfiles if file in afilenames]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [a for a in afilenames for b in bfiles if a == b[0]]
```

your version also worked for me with the example you provided.

```
x = [afile for afile in afilenames for bfile in bfiles if afile in bfile]
```

This also worked.